# Add cache to a running Hazelcast Node

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to add a map to a running hazelcast cluster, but it does not seem to work correctly until I restart the whole cluster (destroying any data already stored there).

I'm trying to add a new map to the hazelcast config. The xml looks like:

```
<map name="com.example.token">
    <map-store enabled="true">
        <class-name>com.example.TokenMapLoader</class-name>
    </map-store>
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <time-to-live-seconds>10800</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">125000</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
</map>
```

I was hoping to be able to do a rolling restart, by updating the config for each node and restarting it, letting it rejoin the existing cluster. When I try it though, the map returns null for any lookup and the MapLoader never gets called, even after all nodes have been updated. I might expect the cluster to not work correctly while when a instance does not have the correct MapLoader, but after all nodes have the new config I assumed the map would start to work.

Is it possible to add a map to a hazelcast cluster without requiring a full cluster restart?

Comment: afaik, if the configuration of a node is not the same of the nodes in a cluster, this node can't join the cluster. What you want is - I think - not possible today.

Answer (score 0):

As Jérémie mentioned, there is no way to dynamically change configuration as of yet in Hazelcast data structures. However, if you're good to use JCache, you can use dynamic configuration which is part of the JCache specification itself.

For Hazelcast data structures we have this on our backlog but it is not yet implemented.